# Page not found - running JSP using tomcat from imported SVN project

Tags: eclipse, svn, tomcat7

I have imported a project using SVN and when I right click on a .jsp file in that project, Run as--> Run on server i get this "The webpage cannot be found"

But it works (right click file-->Run as--> Run on server) when I do it on a hello.jsp I made:

I'm a begginer with SVN and JSP. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: do you have welcome file list in web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You cant - this is unfixable. Brace yourselve! You are doomed.